# Python check if type match a specific type

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find out the type of the object assigned to a variable.

For example if I use pynput

```
print type(key)
```

will return me either a

```
<enum 'key'>
```

if I press alt, ctrl or Return; while if I press a letter or number, I get

```
pynput.keyboard.darwin.KeyCode
```

How do I check for either? I tried to use a comparison with `==` but this didn't work

```
istypeof = type(key)
if istypeof =='key':
    print("is a key")
elif istypeof == "pynput.keyboard.darwin.KeyCode":
    print("is a letter/number")
```

EDIT------------------------

In case you are not used to pynput, I am adding here the full code of the function I have.

```
from pynput import keyboard

class recorder:

    def on_press(self, key):
        print(key)
        istypeof = type(key)
        if istypeof =='key':
            print("is a key")
        elif istypeof == "pynput.keyboard.darwin.KeyCode":
            print("is a letter/number")

    def on_release(self, key):
        print(key)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testme = recorder()

    with key_listener(on_press=testme.on_press, on_release=testme.on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

On a different note; I am looking for the "how do you compare the types, so this should work either if the type is an int, a string, enum or any other object that may be in a variable. Once I understand how you compare types; I can apply the same concept to any other type. Thanks!

Comment: how (or to what) did you assign `key` variable? (sorry, first time I've used the `pynput` package)

Comment: Hi, basically there is a loop where the keyboard.Listener is pinging the system to get a key. and when an event `on_press` or `on_release` is intercepted, it trigger the related event, executing the code in the associated function. I am adding the code in the question so it will be more clear. BTW my question is mostly generic, I am not able to figure out exactly which part of the `type` content you use.